# Is it possible to specify dependencies for dependencies in dub?

Tags: d, dub

I am trying to use https://github.com/ParticlePeter/ErupteD

The problem is that I need a platform specific function which is hidden behind a version. The version itself uses a module called `xcb-d`, which is not insde the dub config file of that library.

```d
// VK_KHR_xcb_surface
version(VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR) {
    public import xcb.xcb;

    enum VK_KHR_XCB_SURFACE_SPEC_VERSION = 6;
    enum VK_KHR_XCB_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME = "VK_KHR_xcb_surface";

    alias VkXcbSurfaceCreateFlagsKHR = VkFlags;

    struct VkXcbSurfaceCreateInfoKHR {
        VkStructureType             sType = VkStructureType.VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_XCB_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
        const(void)*                pNext;
        VkXcbSurfaceCreateFlagsKHR  flags;
        xcb_connection_t*           connection;
        xcb_window_t                window;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ParticlePeter/ErupteD/blob/master/source/erupted/types.d#L3333

There is no configuration for xcb as far as I can see https://github.com/ParticlePeter/ErupteD/blob/master/dub.json

I currently just do

```
dependency "erupted" version="~>1.1.1"
subConfiguration "erupted" "with-derelict-loader"
versions "VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR"
```

> source/erupted/types.d(3335,16): Error: module xcb is in file
>   'xcb/xcb.d' which cannot be read

Is it possible to specify dependencies for dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify "dependencies for dependencies" for dub repos, nor should doing so be necessary.

Because you manually specify `VK_USE_PLATFORM_XCB_KHR`, the Erupted package is not configured to depend on the `xcb-d` project, so it will fail to compile.

There does, however, exist a `dub-platform-xcb-derelict-loader` configuration, which includes both the derelict loader and the XCB platform functions, which seems to be what you want. Use that configuration and remove the version.